# If I declare a class instance with no name, will it stay in memory?

Tags: c++, class, vector, instance, member

I have the following code (I'll skip includes and what have you):

main.cpp

```
std::vector <actor> actors;
int main() {
    actor (2, 3);
}
```

actor.h

```
class actor
{
public:
    int x, y;
    actor(int, int);
};
```

actor.cpp

```
extern std::vector <actor> actors;
actor::actor(int x, int y)
{
    actor::x = x;
    actor::y = y;
    actors.push_back(*this);
}
```

Will the line:

```
    actor (2, 3)
```

actually create an instance of an actor apart from the one being pushed to the actors vector?

Note: If the code doesn't compile, ignore any mistakes. The actual code does compile, but is too convoluted to actually paste here.

Comment: In reply to your note: it’s your job to produce a minimal example which exhibits precisely the problem under scrutiny here. If the actual code is too convoluted, trim it down, or build a minimal example which compiles, please. This is in fact otherwise a very well-written question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will the line:
>
> ```
> actor (2, 3)
> ```
>
> actually create an instance of an actor apart from the one being pushed to the actors vector?

Yes. `actor(2, 3)` will create a *temporary* object of type `actor`, unless it’s part of an expression that is unevaluated<sup>1</sup>. In the constructor of this temporary, a copy (of `*this`) will be pushed onto the stack (but note once again that in an unevaluated expression the constructor will of course not be called).

At the end of the expression which contains `actor(2, 3)`, the temporary will be destroyed. The vector copy will remain untouched.

---

<sup>1</sup> An unevaluated expression is an expression inside a `sizeof(…)`, `typeid(…)`, `decltype(…)` or `noexcept(…)` expression.

Comment: It's unclear. The OP's code doesn't compile, and if the expression is `sizeof(actor(2, 3))`, no pushing will happen.

Comment: No one mentioned `sizeof`, OP only asked about the specific line `actor(2, 3);`

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The point is that not every expression is evaluated, and the desired side effects only happen if evaluation happens. I think that's a sufficiently general point that it's worth making.

Comment: +1 for the only C++ answer on SO that uses the phrase "pushed onto the stack" in a meaningful way.

Comment: @KerrekSB That’s funny because it was actually kind of accidental (I meant to say `vector`). :p But I’ll let it stand since it’s accurate.

Comment: Apologies for it not compiling. It's not the actual code: the actual code is a bit too large to actually paste here. It does compile though, and I just wanted to know if I'd be wasting extra memory or if it's fine the way it is.

Answer (score 4):

It stays "alive" for the duration of the evaluation of the expression which it is a part of and is automatically disposed right after.

Example:

```
actor(2,3); // created and immediately destroyed
actor(2,3)->act(); // created, then acts, then destroyed
std::cout << actor(2,3) << std::endl; // created, streamed, destroyed
```

Gotcha (never do this)

```
actor const& shoot_myself(actor const& a) { return a; }
...
actor const& a = shoot_myself(actor(2,));
a->act(); // "segmentation fault / core dumped"
```

Comment: “even before std::endl is streamed” – uhm. Are you sure about this? I was under the impression (in fact, I still am!) that this is false. The order of evaluation of the sub-expressions is completely undefined. (EDIT: [yup, it’s wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5836569ef816c29c))

Comment: @KonradRudolph - correct, though the order of sub-expressions is clearly left to right in my example, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to place a semicolon in the end of the statement

```
actor (2, 3)
```

There must be

```
actor(2, 3);
```

A temporary object created in this line will be deleted in the same line when the control will be passed to the next statement. Its copy (the copy of the object) will be pushed by the constructor in the vector.

As the result you will have only one object of type actor that is in the vector.

You could keep the temporary object if you would define a const reference initialized by this object. For example

```
const actor &ar = actor( 2, 3 );
```

In this case you had two objects of type actor one that will be pushed in the vector and this temporary object that will be refered to by the const reference.

Here is an example that demonstrates what was said.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct A
{
    int x, y;
    A (int, int);
};

std::vector<A> v;

A::A( int x, int y ) : x( x ), y( y )
{
    v.push_back( *this );   
}

int main() 
{
    const A &ra = A( 2, 3 );

    std::cout << "ra.x = " << ra.x << ", ra.y = " << ra.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v[0].x = " << v[0].x << ", v[0].y = " << v[0].y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
ra.x = 2, ra.y = 3
v[0].x = 2, v[0].y = 3
```

In this example the program outputs values of two different objects.